# Vue.js: load content into DOM depending on file extension

Tags: javascript, file, templates, vue.js

In the past I loaded several text and media data from an object into the DOM via Vue.js. 
BUT sometimes I have images and sometimes videos.
Therefore, I build something like the following:

```
<img id="example-image" :src="item.media" :alt="item.image + 'example pic'" @error="loadVideo()">
<video id="example-video">
<source :src="item.media" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

So if the article contains an image - it shows an image. As soon as it's a video instead (which of course fails to be loaded into an IMG tag) it loads a method which hides the image and instead shows the video.

Unfortunately, this isn't best practice (works flawless in Chrome, but in Safari won't be shown until it's 100% downloaded on the client – byebye traffic)

Therefore, I thought If I may could check the file extension with a method and depending on that load the content with the proper HTML Tag. (something like

```
getFileExtension(filename) {
return filename.slice((filename.lastIndexOf(".") - 1 >>> 0) + 2);
}
```

But maybe one of you got a better idea? Thank you tons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you have is the filename, then you'll have to decide between displaying an image or video based on the extension (as you suggested).

Try something like this:

```vue
<video v-if="isVideo(item.media)">
  <source :src="item.media" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<img v-else :src="item.media">
```

```es6
methods: {
  isVideo(filename) {
    return /\.mp4$/i.test(filename)
  }
}
```

Comment: Love this solution. It's fast, simple and working. Thanks a lot. I was on the right path, as I changed the order of video and image after posting here and tried to use v-if/v-else, but your method made it finally work!